# laser drivers stack SICK LMS1xx stable?

Tags: sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Is it possible to move the sick LMS1xx package into the the laser driver stack?
ros.org/wiki/LMS1xx

ros.org/wiki/laser_drivers

- contains packages for the hokuyo lasers and packages for sick lms2xx
  because i noticed some people think that ROS did not support sick lms1xx

this person did not find the lms1xx driver until he made his own
answers.ros.org/question/29926/made-driver-for-lms151-what-should-i-do-next/

this is where i found the LMS1xx package ros.org/wiki/Sensors

Also I am considering buying a SICK LMS111 for a university project. I am wondering weather the SICK LMS1xx ros node is stable and works for the SICK LMS111?

I noticed in the wiki there is very little documentation (in comparison to the other drivers)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54515/laser-drivers-stack-sick-lms1xx-stable?/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the question may be old but I'm facing the same problem.
I grabbed the lms1xx package at https://github.com/RCPRG-ros-pkg/RCPRG_laser_drivers
The package is good for Hydro.

It works well.

The problem is still the lack of documentation. And the code seems good only for Ethernet connection, non serial.

---

Originally posted by [mpp](https://answers.ros.org/users/8286/mpp/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0